# Draggable UIView does not move smoothly and is only draggable for a little distance (Video included)

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, draggable

The video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8_xCTJAld9Y&feature=youtu.be
. Here you can see my issue, and I do not know what exactly is wrong. I cant move it like I want.

I have a draggable UIView, which has a custom class:

```
import UIKit

class UIViewDraggable: UIView {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

}


override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first;
    let location = touch?.location(in: self.superview);
    if(location != nil)
    {
    self.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: location!.x-self.frame.size.width/2, y: location!.y-self.frame.size.height/2);
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    }
}
```

**I create the UIView with a button tap:**

```
@IBAction func buttonAddSubviewTextTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let label = UIView()
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21)
    label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
    label.backgroundColor = .red
    self.viewImagePreview.addSubview(label)
    self.viewImagePreview.bringSubviewToFront(label)

}
```

How can I implement a fully smoothly draggable UIView?

**Final Solution to make button created view draggable within its parentview:**

```
@IBAction func buttonAddSubviewTextTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(draggedView(_:)))

    let label = UIView()
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21)
    label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
    label.backgroundColor = .red
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    label.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    self.viewImagePreview.addSubview(label)
    self.viewImagePreview.bringSubviewToFront(label)

}


// Function to drag a view
@objc func draggedView(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    guard let createdView = sender.view else {return}
    createdView.bringSubviewToFront(viewImagePreview)

    if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {

        let point = sender.location(in: self.viewImagePreview)
        if let parentView = self.viewImagePreview {

            let superBounds = CGRect(x: parentView.bounds.origin.x, y: parentView.bounds.origin.y, width: parentView.bounds.size.width - 2, height: parentView.bounds.size.height - 2)

            if (superBounds.contains(point)) {
                let translation = sender.translation(in: parentView)
                createdView.center = CGPoint(x: createdView.center.x + translation.x, y: createdView.center.y + translation.y)
                sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: parentView)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `UIPanGestureRecogniser`? It could get your job done much easier

Comment: Is UIPanGestureRecogniser a use case for me, since I want to add multiple UIViews?

Comment: Would be helpful if you could provide a gist about your use case

Comment: On a side note, you could directly set `yourView.center` to be the `location` instead of having to set `yourView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: location!.x-self.frame.size.width/2, y: location!.y-self.frame.size.height/2)`

Answer (score 1):

Add a `panGesture` to your View and then based on the touch location, updated your `view.center`

```
let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panView))
self.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
```

then use it as:

```
@objc func panView(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let location = pan.location(in: self.superView) // get pan location

    switch pan.state {
    case .began:
        print("began")
    case .changed:
        self.center = location
        // updated your frames here
    default:
        print("nothing")
    }
 }
```

---

Also for your case,

try replacing

```
self.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: location!.x-self.frame.size.width/2, y: location!.y-self.frame.size.height/2);
```

to

```
self.center = location
```

Comment: I do not know why, but the PanGesture is not called. I have edited my post..

Comment: @JohnDole you may add your pan gesture in `UIViewDraggable ` class `init` method.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I used a normal UIView, not my custom class. But I will google for the Pan Approach - thank you for your input

Comment: Keshu, can I kindly ask you to look at my Edit2? I am now able to move the whole view when I move the UIView which I created via button tap. How can I pass the created UIView to my @objc func draggedView(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer)?

Comment: @JohnDole in your `draggedView` function, you can get your view by `let labelView = sender.view`